# Formatting issue using some commands combined with lists (itemize and enumerate)

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I would like to have a list of items using `itemize` and command.

It does not work if you have a command just before `\myitem`. Using command does not produce an item.

`\iexitembegin` is giving an error of formatting.

Would you have a solution? I would need really a possible way, ie. it is an important issue for daily use.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Article},%
    pdfauthor={Username},%
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\partone}[1]{
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt, itemindent=-0ex,leftmargin=4.3ex]
\item[--] {\bfseries #1}
\end{itemize}
\smallskip
\smallskip
\smallskip
}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item[--] #1}
\newcommand{\myitembegin}{\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]}
\newcommand{\myitemend}{\end{itemize}}

\title{Hello}
\date{}
\author{} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\partone{hello title}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
\item[--] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
\item[--] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
\item[--] test
\end{itemize}
\myitembegin
\myitem{hello world}
\myitem{lkdjfajdsfa}
\myitem{lkdjfajdsfa}
\myitem{toudouldsafjdslkdjfajdsfa}
\myitemend

\end{document}
```

Comment: As of now, your code is not compilable for several reasons: (1) `hypersetup` can only be used when `hyperref` is loaded. (2) You load `enumerate` but use the `itemize` environment. Try loading the `enumitem` package instead.

Comment: Can you also post the error message which pops up? "Error of formatting" is not really helpful at the moment..

Comment: Instead of defining `\myitembegin` and `\myitemend` you should define a real environment. See the `enumitem` manual for more information about defining new list environments derivated from `itemize`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Schweinebacke wrote, you should define a real environment rather than using \newcommand, which can have unexpected results, when used for more complicated things than just inserting a small macro.

The `enumitem`package can do exactly what you want. I copied your MWE and edited it to perform the task you're looking for. Basically, I just changed `\myitembegin`to `\newlist{myitem}{2}`, where `2` is the max depth of the list.

Next line is `\setlist[myitem]{key-val options}`, where you define the item label and other list-specific options. The complete example looks like this (I added the `hyperref` package to accomodate your MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Article},%
    pdfauthor={Username},%
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true}


\newcommand{\partone}[1]{
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt, itemindent=-0ex,leftmargin=4.3ex]
\item[--] {\bfseries #1}
\end{itemize}
\smallskip
\smallskip
\smallskip
}

\newlist{myitem}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[myitem]{label={--},noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}

\title{Hello}
\date{}
\author{} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\partone{hello title}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
\item[--] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
\item[--] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
\item[--] test
\end{itemize}
\begin{myitem}
\item hello world
\item lkdjfajdsfa
\item lkdjfajdsfa
\item toudouldsafjdslkdjfajdsfa
\end{myitem}

\end{document}
```

Most of the packages are not used for anything particular, but I left them in the MWE to show that they do not interfere with the desired output, as shown below
[image: pdflatex output]

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of `itemsep=-1ex`. You can just define your own `itemize` variant.

In the code below I dropped all unnecessary packages; for your document add the ones you need, of course.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\partone}[1]{%
\begin{itemize}[
  label=--,
  topsep=0pt,
  itemsep=-1ex,
  partopsep=0pt,
  parsep=0pt,
  itemindent=-0ex,
  leftmargin=4.3ex
]
\item \textbf{#1}
\end{itemize}
\addvspace{\medskipamount}
}

\newenvironment{myitemize}
 {\begin{itemize}[label=--,noitemsep, topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\partone{hello title}
\begin{myitemize}
\item hello world
\item lkdjfajdsfa
\item lkdjfajdsfa
\item toudouldsafjdslkdjfajdsfa
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]